# Ошибка компиляции - не видит сборку System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0

Tags: c#, f#, youtrack

Решил переписать один свой проект по управлению YT на языке F#.
Взял и просто подтянул nuget библиотеки YouTrackSharp которая автоматически потянула за собой зависимости из того же nuget.

Вот код на F# тестовой консоли которая падает с ошибкой:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    printfn "Start..."

    let con = new BearerTokenConnection(url, token)
    let iserv = new IssuesService(con)

    try
    let issue = iserv.GetIssue("SLE-1800", false).Result
    //issue.Fields.Count |> printfn "Count %i"
    issue.Fields |> Seq.iter (fun a -> printfn "%s : %A/%A" a.Name a.Value a.ValueId)
    with
    | x -> errorfn "ERROR: by %A" x
           printfn "Closing..."

    Console.ReadLine()

    0 // возвращение целочисленного кода выхода
```

Ничего сверхъестественного, но выскакивает такая ошибка:

> ERROR: by System.IO.FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или
>   сборку "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей.
>   Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на
>   сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040) Имя файла:
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    в
>   YouTrackSharp.Issues.IssuesService.GetIssue(String issueId, Boolean
>   wikifyDescription)    в Program.main(String[] argv) в
>   C:\Users\s.zorin\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\LogExpert\RAVR\Program.fs:строка 27
>
> Предупреждение: регистрация привязки сборок выключена. Чтобы включить
>   регистрацию ошибок привязки сборок, установите значение параметра
>   реестра [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) в 1.
>   Примечание. Регистрация ошибок привязки сборок может привести к
>   некоторому снижению производительности. Чтобы отключить эту функцию,
>   удалите параметр реестра [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Все решается, если я просто скопирую эту библиотеку из проекта на C#, но при следующей компиляции все конечно же ломается и делать копирование постоянно просто нецелесообразно для меня, так как проект будет расти в другие библиотеки.

Непонятно почему nuget затянул не ту версию на F# и как это можно исправить? В самом nuget я не нашел конкретно эту версию, что бы откатить. Есть 4.1.1, но происходит то же самое.

Comment: наверное можно использовать `paket` чтобы обойти проблему =)

Comment: Какая у вас версия пакета сейчас/была?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, автоматом установилась последняя версия, пробовал откатывать, ничего не получилось, что Вы имеете ввиду под использованием paket?

Comment: [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/)

Comment: В качестве обходного решения можно отредактировать проектный фаил и явно задать ссылку на библиотеку, то есть вместо `<Reference Include="System.Net.Http">...` укажите `<Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
        <Private>True</Private>
        <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

Comment: (путь к библиотеке поставьте свой =))

Comment: но все-таки я бы рассмотрел вариант с использованием `paket`

Comment: ...вопрос решен?